# Java Tile Game - Collision Detection

Tags: java, collision-detection, tile

I am making a java game using tiles. I am having trouble with the collision element. I am defining rectangles for each tile on the map, and another rectangle for the player. What I am having trouble with is knowing which side the player is coming from when it hits the rectangle, and then pushing the player off in the direction the player came from. I have already made a method that checks how much the character is inside the rectangle, so it can know how much to push it out, but I can't figure out how to tell which side the character is coming from.

here is my current collision methoe - note rect1 is the character and rect2 is the tile

```
public void collision(Rectangle rect1, Rectangle rect2) {
    float xAdd;
    float xAdd2;
    float yAdd;
    float yAdd2;

    boolean hitRight = false;
    boolean hitLeft = false;
    boolean hitTop = false;
    boolean hitBot = false;

    Vector2f rect1Origin = new Vector2f(rect1.x, rect1.y);
    Vector2f rect2Origin = new Vector2f(rect2.x, rect2.y);
    Vector2f rect1Mid = new Vector2f((rect1.x + rect1.width) / 2,(rect1.y + rect1.height) / 2);
    Vector2f rect2Mid = new Vector2f((rect2.x + rect2.width) / 2,(rect2.y + rect2.height) / 2);

    Vector2f rect1A = new Vector2f(rect1Origin.x + rect1.width, rect1.y);
    Vector2f rect1B = new Vector2f(rect1Origin.x, rect1Origin.y+ rect1.height);
    Vector2f rect1C = new Vector2f(rect1Origin.x + rect1.width,rect1Origin.y + rect1.height);

    Vector2f rect2A = new Vector2f(rect2Origin.x + rect2.width, rect2.y);
    Vector2f rect2B = new Vector2f(rect2Origin.x, rect2Origin.y
            + rect2.height);
    Vector2f rect2C = new Vector2f(rect2Origin.x + rect2.width,
            rect2Origin.y + rect2.height);

    xAdd = rect2C.x - rect1B.x;
    xAdd2 = rect1C.x - rect2B.x;

    yAdd = rect2A.y - rect1B.y;
    yAdd2 = rect2C.y - rect1A.y;


    if (rect1Mid.y < rect2Mid.y) {
        if (rect1.intersects(rect2)) {
            y_pos += yAdd;
        }
    }
    if (rect1Mid.y > rect2Mid.y) {
        if (rect1.intersects(rect2)) {
            System.out.println(yAdd2);
            y_pos += yAdd2;
        }

    }
    if(rect1Mid.x > rect2Mid.x){
        if(rect1.intersects(rect2)){
            hitRight = true; x_pos += xAdd;
        }
    } 
    if(rect1Mid.x< rect2Mid.x){ 
          if(rect1.intersects(rect2)) {
              x_pos += -xAdd2;
          } 
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep two positions for your character - where the it is (as of last frame, move, etc.), and where you want to move it. Then only move it if you don't detect collision - if you don't allow for corrupt state, you don't have to fix it.

**Edit:** The `collision` method should be `boolean` - it should be done **before** actually moving the character, like

```
if (!collision(character, tile))
{
    doMove(character);
}
else
{
    //custom handling if required
}
```

**Edit2:** The previous would work only for a small step, if you need a partial move, you really need to know the character's original position, like `move(originalPosition, desiredPosition, tile)`, where you can deduce the direction from the `originalPosition` and the `tile`.

The main point is, you don't actually move the character, before you have a valid position for it.

Comment: This will lead to strange situation, depending on the time step interval.

Comment: @Matzi Not really, thing of it validation before executing some user command - if it doesn't validate, you can do custom handling.

Comment: @KirilRaychev I don't really understand what you're trying to say

Comment: @grimrader22 I tried to make it more clear, please ask if it is not good enough yet.

Comment: @KirilRaychev From personal experience, it is not like that. :) It can have small evvect, if the step is small, but the problem is present.

Comment: @KirilRaychev That still won't fix the problem because if the character hits the rectangle, it will not be able to move away from the rectangle because the domove method won't be able to call. That is why I need to find the side the character is coming from, so I can disable that part of the domove method

Answer (score 1):

First of all, any *Sprite* (the character and the tile here) should have four members: xPos, yPos, xVec, yVec.  With that in mind, you know where the character was and will be in the next frame.

```
sprite.xPos += sprite.xVec;
sprite.yPos += sprite.yVec;
```

Also take a look at your code, you should improve the propositions (for instance, you check *if(rect1.intersects(rect2))* in the four *if* statements).  Instead, check only once for the *intersects()*, and inside check for each possible case (left, right, top, bottom hit).

Finally, the collision method should receive 2 sprites objects (for instance, *sprite1* and *sprite2*), and then check for the *intersects()* method, taking into account the original positions of both sprites and its vectors.  If the sprites intersect in the new position, then you invert the object's vector accordingly.

Comment: What do the xVec and yVec variables represent?

Comment: I'm sorry i wasn't so clear, those are the directional vectors of the sprite (you could also use Vector2f or Point2D).  The value can be interpreted as the speed of the sprite in each direction.  So if the character hits the tile exactly from the left, xVec is a positive value, and yVec is 0; and after the hit, xVec should have the same value, but now negative.  Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're saying, sorry if i'm being dumb. Would the xand y Vecs be the velocity?

Comment: Right.  Supose sprite is on xPos = 10, yPos = 20, and xVec = 3, yVec = 2.  So, in the next frame, xPos will be 13 and yPos will be 22.  After that, xVec and yVec could be the same (a ship in space), reduced (friction, gravity, etc.) or increased (throttle).  In the case of a collision, xVec and yVec will change depending the position of the other sprite.  So back to the example, if the character has a xVec of 3, and yVec of 1 and hits from the left (character.xPos < tile.xPos), the "bounce" is achieved setting -3 to xVec and leaving yVec with 1 (you can add a little random if you like)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can detect the collision with your code. Here is a way to determine the position of your character with respect to the rectangle object.

1. Find the middle point of the rectangle. ( Rx,Ry).
2. Find the middle point of your character sprite. ( Sx,Sy).
3. Now you can compare Rx,Ry , Sx , Sy to determine in which side is Sx and Sy of Rx and Ry
4. for ex:

   ```
   if Sx < Rx then
     Sx = left side of Rx
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Was struggling with this myself, but after some thinking this check can be done by having all your entities in a List, in my code I had to block the player from moving through blocks. All blocks is in a List. Now, when checking players position I create a new Rectangle and put the players position one frame forward in the direction the update will happened next frame, if the  the rectangle intersects that update for that direction will not happened. Heres my code for this:

```
    if (isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)) {
        if(!collisionWithBlocks(1)){
            pl.x = pl.x - updatePlayerPosition;
        }
    }
    if (isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)) {
        if(!collisionWithBlocks(0)){
            pl.x = pl.x + updatePlayerPosition;
        }
    }
    if (isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_UP)) {
        if(!collisionWithBlocks(3)){
            pl.y = pl.y - updatePlayerPosition;
        }
    }
    if (isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)) {
        if(!collisionWithBlocks(2)){
            pl.y = pl.y + updatePlayerPosition;
        }
    }
```

collisionWithBlocks():

```
public boolean collisionWithBlocks(int side){
    for(Block b : main.blocks){
        Rectangle block = b.getBounds();
        Rectangle player = null;
        if(side == 0){
            player = new Rectangle(pl.x + updatePlayerPosition, pl.y, pl.getWidth(), pl.getHeight());
        } else if(side == 1){
            player = new Rectangle(pl.x - updatePlayerPosition, pl.y, pl.getWidth(), pl.getHeight());
        } else if(side == 2){
            player = new Rectangle(pl.x, pl.y + updatePlayerPosition, pl.getWidth(), pl.getHeight());
        } else if(side == 3){
            player = new Rectangle(pl.x, pl.y - updatePlayerPosition, pl.getWidth(), pl.getHeight());
        }

        if(player.intersects(block)){
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

updatePlayerPosition is 2, and changes in my code but enough about that.
In your case, I recommend putting the entities in a List and then checking like I did over.